# How to bind content in a headertemplate of Panorama Item

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, data-binding, datatemplate

I am working on Wp7
I have created a header template for Panorama Item Header in application resource (App.xaml):

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MainPanoramaHeaderTemplate">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding title}" Margin="0,15,0,0"
                           Name="CurrentTitle"
                               FontSize="37" FontWeight="SemiBold"
                       Foreground="{StaticResource CurrentThemeColorLight}"
                       ></TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
```

I have applied this template to Panorama Item :

```
<controls:Panorama Name="MainPanorama" Margin="0,76,0,0">
            <controls:PanoramaItem
                Name="pano1"
                HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource MainPanoramaHeaderTemplate}">
                <Grid></Grid>
            </controls:PanoramaItem>
```

and in code behind i tried to bind the pano1.Datacontext.
but nothing happened?
Actually i have a panorama item which can have 2-3 different header titles in different situation.

How can I do this?

thanks in advance.

Comment: You tried to bind pano1.DataContext to what exactly?

Comment: i tried a object and a list of a class having property string title.

Comment: Have you implemented the class to enable bindings/notifications (http://myprogrammingdial.blogspot.com/2012/03/property-binding-using.html)? Are you getting any binding errors in the output window?

Comment: where are you initializing the title which you have binded and how have you binded the DataContext? can you put some code??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
        <DataTemplate x:Key="MainPanoramaHeaderTemplate">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Margin="0,15,0,0"
                       Name="CurrentTitle"
                           FontSize="37" FontWeight="SemiBold"
                   Foreground="{StaticResource CurrentThemeColorLight}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
```

And

```
        <controls:PanoramaItem Header="{Binding title}" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource MainPanoramaHeaderTemplate}">
```

It worked for me. Let me know if its not working. I will help you out further :)

Note: I have title property in my ViewModel and have used the below statement to give a reference of it to the dataContext on the mainPage

```
        DataContext = App.ViewModel;
```